# Spring cloud stream with cloud function fails to convert kafka message to pojo with "No type info header exception"

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am using spring cloud stream dependencies with 3.2.8 version,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And override dlq and retry as below

```
 @Bean
  ListenerContainerWithDlqAndRetryCustomizer kafkaDlqAndRetryCustomizer(KafkaTemplate<String, Event> template) {
    return new ListenerContainerWithDlqAndRetryCustomizer() {
      @Override
      public void configure(
          AbstractMessageListenerContainer<?, ?> container, String destinationName,
          String group,
          BiFunction<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception, TopicPartition> dlqDestinationResolver,
          BackOff backOff) {
        DefaultErrorHandler handler = getErrorHandler(template);
        container.setCommonErrorHandler(handler);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean retryAndDlqInBinding(String destinationName, String group) {
        return false;
      }
    };
  }
```

currently when a message is posted not able to convert the message to Pojo for a stream listener

```
application config:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        autodetect: false
        definition: processCommand
      bindings:
        processCommand-in-0:
          destination: command-topic
          group: group-1
          consumer:
            useNativeDecoding: true

pojo to be mapped
@Bean
  public Consumer<Command> processCommand() {
    return command -> {
System.out.println(command);
}
}
```

on consuming message from kafka getting below error

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No type information in headers and no default type provided
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:583)
at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer.deserialize(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.java:201)
... 23 common frames omitted

Comment: You're using native decoding, but you don't show your deserializer configuration. When using the JsonDeserializer to receive data from a foreign source (no headers) you must configure the deserializer with type information. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#json-serde If you don't use native decoding, the framework will detect the type from your consumer bean definition.